# if else в конструкторе словаря при генерации

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

```
d = dict({line[0]:line[1:] for line in lst if len(line) > 1})
```

хочу добавить else, но выдает NameError, мол d not definned перед setdefault-ом:

`d = dict({line[0]:line[1:] if len(line) > 1 else d.setdefault(line[0], []) for line in lst})`

не понимаю как добавить ключ с пустым листом, как значение.

Comment: У вас line какой имеет тип?

Comment: сам lst это 2м массив. line - перебирает каждый лист в листе. сам запутался в ответе, но думаю вы поймете о чем я

Comment: Тогда почему бы не просто `d = {line[0]: line[1:] for line in lst}`

Comment: а если len(line) == 1? при этом нужно создать ключ с пустым листом как значение

Comment: Он и создастся.

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!!!)

Comment: Вообще, срез, выходящий за границы списка, «срежет» пустой список: `line = ['a']; print(line[9999:] == [])  # → True`

Comment: спасибо за объяснение. теперь все ясно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С примером:

```
def my_test(line):
    """
    >>> my_test([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    {1: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
    >>> my_test([5])
    {5: []}
    """
    return dict([(line[0], line[1:]) if len(line) > 1 else [line[0], []] ])
                                                                      # for line in lines])
```